# Sum in constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, sum

I'm trying to solve the problem. When the user enter two numbers via  ** prompt **, after the display shows the final result. Simple constructor, but this code only accepts the first value, I cannot force it to take the second one too, in order for sum both values

```
function Num (firstNum) {
    this.firstNum = firstNum;
    this.read = function() {
        this.value = this.x + this.firstNum; {
            return this.x = +prompt('a');
        }
    };
}
let num = new Num(10); 
num.read(); 
num.read(); 

alert(num.value);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is `this.x`? What is `num.value`?

Comment: _Everyone_ here is trying to solve a problem. :) Please revise your post title to ask a clear , _specific_ question. Then revise your post to add details per h0r53's comment.

Comment: @h0r53 all what I want. execute the "propmt" - twice and so that the function remembers the numbers of prompt value and shows it as alert. I tried to do via "this.value += this.x + this.firstNum;" but turns out, this. cant work with "+="

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have suggested you should probably edit your question to make it clearer. But if I had to take a guess here's my answer:

Lookup "curry functions" or "partial application". You can basically use closures to stash the value from the first prompt until you receive the value from the second.

```
    const sumTwo = firstNum => secondNum => firstNum + secondNum;

    // then when you want to use it;
    const plusTen = sumTwo(prompt(10);

    const resultA = plusTen(prompt(2)); // this will be 12
    const resultB = plusTen(prompt(5)); // this will be 15
```

Answer (score 0):

*solve*

```
function Num (firstNum) {
    this.value = firstNum;
    this.read = function() {
        this.value += +prompt('a?', 0);
    };
}

let num = new Num(10); 
num.read(); 
num.read(); 

alert(num.value);
```